# Django CMS test - can't find namespace

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-urls, django-cms

I've got a very strange problem with Django CMS tests. When I run: `./manage.py test --settings=my_project.test_settings` I get that error:

> ERROR: test_guest_list_view
>   (apps.news.tests.test_views.NewsListViewTest) Tests if guest can't see
>   disabled entries
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/robert/work/projects/my_project/apps/news/tests/test_views.py",
>   line 52, in test_guest_list_view
>       response = self.client.get(self._get_list_url())   File "/home/robert/work/projects/my_project/apps/news/tests/test_views.py",
>   line 17, in _get_list_url
>       return reverse("news:list")   File "/home/robert/.virtualenvs/my_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py",
>   line 532, in reverse
>       key) NoReverseMatch: u'news' is not a registered namespace

**But when I ran tests only for that app everything works fine - all tests pass.**

That's my very simple test class so far:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.test.utils import override_settings

from cms.test_utils.testcases import CMSTestCase

from apps.accounts.tests.factories import CustomUserFactory
from .factories import NewsFactory
from ..models import News


class BaseNewsTestCase(CMSTestCase):
    def _get_list_url(self):
        """Returns URL to objects list"""
        return reverse("news:list")

    def _create_data_structure(self):
        """Created test data"""
        # add objects
        self.disabled = NewsFactory(is_visible=False)
        self.enabled = NewsFactory()
        NewsFactory()
        NewsFactory()

        self.user = CustomUserFactory(username='user', password='user')

        # privileged_user
        self.privileged_user = CustomUserFactory(username='p_user',
                                                 password='p_user')

        # add permissions
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(News)
        permissions_list = ('add_news', 'change_news', 'delete_news')
        permissions = Permission.objects.filter(content_type=content_type,
                                                codename__in=permissions_list)

        self.privileged_user.user_permissions.add(*permissions)


@override_settings(ROOT_URLCONF='apps.news.tests.urls')
class NewsListViewTest(BaseNewsTestCase):
    def test_guest_list_view(self):
        """Tests if guest can't see disabled entries"""
        self._create_data_structure()

        response = self.client.get(self._get_list_url())
        objects = response.context['object_list']

        self.assertEqual(len(objects), 3)
        for obj in objects:
            self.assertNotEqual(obj, self.disabled)
```

and test urls:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns, include

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^news/', include('apps.news.urls', namespace='news')),
    url(r'', include('cms.urls')),
)
```

Any clue what can cause that problem? I follow this, to test my CMA apphook (http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extending_cms/testing.html)

I have the same tests pattern in different app in that project but it doesn't throw that error.

Comment: I'm a little confused here. Are you testing an apphook? If so, you shouldn't have anything about that app in your urls.py, right?

Comment: @mkoistinen look at this: http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extending_cms/testing.html#resolving-view-names - this is what I do. In my CMS that app is as an apphook, but in my tests I test that as normal app to check its functionality.

Comment: The problem is that when I run my all tests I get that error. When I run tests only for that particular app - it passes

Comment: What if instead of 'namespace' you used url(... app_name='news')

Comment: Fails, even in tests for that particular app.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure what's up. I'm using namespaced apps all the time, and I normally just use namespace=.... which version of Django are you using?

Comment: Also, where is your apps.news.urls? Perhaps that is just not loading?

Comment: Django==1.6.6, django-cms==3.0.5. My base app urls ale placed correctly in /news/ and my test urls are placed in /news/tests/ - testing that particular app works so I assume the app files are correct.

Comment: Can you prove that these urls are loading?

Comment: Perhaps we should continue this on IRC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.
Instead of using `@override_settings(ROOT_URLCONF='myapp.tests.urls')` for my TestCases, as suggested in [Django CMS docs](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extending_cms/testing.html#resolving-view-names) I used the Django way found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.urls).

So for each TestCase I do this, for example:

```
class NewsListViewTest(CMSTestCase):
    urls = 'apps.news.tests.urls'
```

Comment: the link is not valid